# Adding widgets to the dashboard

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have set of widgets and I am adding all the widgets on the dashboard and I have to make it resizable and draggable. At the same time  I have to make sure that each widget should not overlap on each other also, I should also make sure that I should not allow users to access multiple widgets at the same time kindly suggest me some solution and I am using jquery and HTML5 along with CSS at the back end I am using servlets and along with mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set all widgets [resizable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/) and [draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/) using JQueryUI:

```
$('#widget1').resizable();
$('#widget1').draggable();

// ....

$('#widgetN').resizable();
$('#widgetN').draggable();
```

You need to study both plugins and adapt them for your own purposes. To limit multiple access for widgets, you can just hide them. Without more information and a little source code, we can't help you. Please, post more information.